# Data driven unit test breaking entity framework connection

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, data-driven-tests

I have an application that uses entity framework. I am writing a unit test in which I would like to use data driven testing from a CSV file.

However, when I run the test, I get an error that the sqlserver provider cannot be loaded:

> Initialization method UnitTest.CalculationTest.MyTestInitialize threw
>   exception. System.InvalidOperationException:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

1. If I remove the data driven aspects and just test a single value, then the test works.
2. If I just use the data driven aspects and remove the Entity Framework stuff, then the test works.

So, its only when I try to use data driven test with entity framework active at the same time do I get the error. So, where am I going wrong here?

Here's my test method:

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("Calculations")
, DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV"
           , "ConvertedMeanProfileDepth.csv", "ConvertedMeanProfileDepth#csv"
           , Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)
, DeploymentItem("ConvertedMeanProfileDepth.csv")]
public void ConvertedMeanProfileDepthTest()
{
    ConvertedMeanProfileDepth target = new ConvertedMeanProfileDepth();
    Decimal mpd = decimal.Parse(this.TestContext.DataRow["mpd"].ToString());
    Decimal expected = decimal.Parse(this.TestContext.DataRow["converted"].ToString());
    Decimal actual;
    actual = target.Calculate(mpd);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to work it out in the end. For future reference, here's the solution:

Rob Lang's post, [Entity Framework upgrade to 6 configuration and nuget magic](http://robsneuron.blogspot.co.za/2013/11/entity-framework-upgrade-to-6.html), reminded me of the issue here:

> When a type cannot be loaded for a DLL that is referenced in a
>   project, it usually means that it has not been copied to the output
>   bin/ directory. When you're not using a type from a referenced
>   library, it will not be copied.

And this will raise its ugly head the moment you use deployment items in your tests. If you use a deployment item in your test, then all of the **required** binaries are copied to the deployment directory. Problem is, if you are using dynamically loaded items, then the test suite does not know it has to copy those items.

With Entity Framework, this means that your providers will not be copied to the deployment location and you will receive the error as per my question.

To resolve the issue, simply ensure that your entity framework provider is also marked as a deployment item.

So, note the inclusion of **DeploymentItem(@"EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll")** in my test attributes. All works perfectly from here:

```
 [TestMethod, TestCategory("Calculations")
    , DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV"
               , "ConvertedMeanProfileDepth.csv", "ConvertedMeanProfileDepth#csv"
               , Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)
    , DeploymentItem("ConvertedMeanProfileDepth.csv")
    , DeploymentItem(@"EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll")]
    public void ConvertedMeanProfileDepthTest()
    {
        ConvertedMeanProfileDepth target = new ConvertedMeanProfileDepth();
        Decimal mpd = decimal.Parse(this.TestContext.DataRow["mpd"].ToString());
        Decimal expected = decimal.Parse(this.TestContext.DataRow["converted"].ToString());
        Decimal actual;
        actual = target.Calculate(mpd);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```